# Qubes OS USB drive with boot partition broke

Tags: boot, partition, usb, qubes

I had the boot partition of my Qubes installation on an external USB drive but it broke and I could save the files. How can I make a grub2 boot partiton to
boot the OS again?

Comment: Maybe try https://www.supergrubdisk.org/wizard-restore-grub-with-super-grub2-disk/

Answer (score -1):

Use live operating system to replace your corrupted boot folder

Comment: How would you complete said task? Please edit your post to include these details otherwise this is not an answer. Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to U&L! @Surajit Karmakar! Please add more details to your answer because your answer doesn't provide clarified steps to solve the question! Thank's!